# MQTT vs JBOSS remoting

Tags: jboss, network-programming, mqtt

We have a java application that has 2 remote components

1. jboss-gatein web application
2. standalone java app

Currently we communicate between 2 components using JBoss remoting.
I have heard about MQTT as light weight reliable.

Is it really better than Jboss remoting?
If so how can we use it?

Comment: This question is too broad: What exactly is "JBoss remoting" in your case: EJB/MDB/JMS? What have you tried?

Comment: It is a networking api provided by jboss.It supports various modes of interaction, including invocations, one way messaging, and asynchronous callbacks.This link contain a sample: [link]http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-remoting/jboss-remoting-tutorial

Comment: To be honest I have never heard of that, so just one thought: If you migrated, you would replace a "proprietary" JBoss API with another one. If there is no special reason, I would use standard EJB/webservice (sync) or MDB/JMS (async) APIs: I would say the tight integration of the implementation (EJB/MDB) and the protocol (RMI/JMS) seems to be simpler.